# Webpack configured React Components not affected by css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I am learning react, and I configured webpack instead of using create-react-app with webpack 4. I have applied styles to the components but the styles are not affecting the components but the background-colour I set in the css file is affecting the page. what could be the problem? No error message is being displayed. See the webpack.config.js file below and the code for the component

Webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const paths = {
    DIST: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    SRC: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
};

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: "./src/index.html",
    filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: path.join(paths.SRC, 'index.js'),
    output: {
        path: paths.DIST,
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },

    module:{
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },

            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader"
                    },

                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options:{
                            modules: true,
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            localIndentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
                            sourceMap: true,
                            minimize: true,
                            camelCase:true
                        }
                    }

                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        htmlPlugin,
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],

    devServer: {
        // contentBase: paths.JS,
        // publicPath: paths.DIST,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: port,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        open:true,
        //hot: true,
        inline: true
    }
};
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './index.css';

class App extends Component{
    render(){
        const helloWorld = 'Welcome to the Road to learn React';
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <h2>{helloWorld}</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: how are you setting styles?

Comment: how are you setting styles? In react style attribute accepts a javascript object with camelCased properties and not the normal properties that we give in css class. So you should give something like style={{ backgroundColor: 'red'}}

Comment: If you're trying to utilize CSS Modules, I believe you need to import your style sheet with a name, `import styles from './index.css'` and then reference the css class name from the imported object. `className="{styles.app}"`.

Comment: If you look at the code above, there is a line imported the css. It works that way when you are using create-react-app. It doesn't work with the one I setup with webpack.

Comment: @Kyle Lussier you were right, however, the className should be like: className={styles.app} without the quotes

Comment: @DavidEssien Ah, correct. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. 
at the top,

```
import styles from './index.css';
```

then in the component

```
<div className={styles.app}>
```